# Rails inverse of pluck()/select()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, attributes, return, render

I'm building a `Rails` API and I would like to know if there is a way to return the attributes of my object, but I don't want to return all of the attributes. Is there a way to prevent certain attributes from being returned? For example, I would not want to return the database IDs or the timestamps

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about calling the `except` [method](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) on your object attributes:
`your_object.attributes.except('id')`

Answer (score 2):

Using ActiveModel::Serializer, you can specify which attributes to be added in the response of each serializer.

[Refer](https://blog.codeship.com/building-a-json-api-with-rails-5/)